# SQL Aggregating sum of minutes for specific time intervals within the same day/week (Phone states)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble visualizing how to aggregate the sum of minutes from time intervals within a given day based on phone system codes.  I have a query written to show the actual sequence of events throughout the day but I need to sum up the intervals (e.g. time between login and logout, time in a 'Not Ready' status, etc.):

```
SELECT -- bunch of information (aa.TimeStamp is included in this)
FROM AGENTACTIVITY as aa
JOIN EXTINFORMATION ext ON aa.AgentNum=ext.ExtNum
WHERE aa.LocalDay>20181118 and aa.LocalDay<20181126
      and aa.AgentNum in ('10', '20', '30', '40', '50')
ORDER by aa.AgentNum, aa.Time_Stamp;
```

There are various Activity codes that are assigned within the system:

- Login = 3
- Logout = 4
- Ready = 5
- Not Ready = 6

The results returned from my query above look like this:

```
TimeStamp             AgentNum  AgentName  ActivityCode
2018-11-19 07:53:06      10      Jane           3
2018-11-19 08:14:11      10      Jane           6
2018-11-19 08:19:12      10      Jane           5
2018-11-19 11:53:08      10      Jane           4
2018-11-19 13:01:16      10      Jane           3
2018-11-19 14:53:06      10      Jane           6
2018-11-19 14:59:16      10      Jane           5
2018-11-19 15:22:22      10      Jane           6
2018-11-19 15:31:25      10      Jane           5
2018-11-19 16:53:10      10      Jane           4
```

So I know when folks are logging in and out and also entering a 'Not Ready' status and then going back into 'Ready'.  What I need to get out of this is the following:

- Total Amount of Time (in minutes) spent in a Not Ready Status
- Total Amount of Time (in minutes) spent Logged In

From these two items I can figure out Total Available Time (Total Time Logged In - Total Time Not Ready).

The expected output would look like:

```
Date        AgentNum   AgentName   TotalTimeLoggedIn  TotalTimeNotReady  TotalTimeAvailable
2018-11-19     10        Jane           472                 20                 452
```

I hope this was clear and makes sense.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your sample data doesn't help much here, because nowhere do we see a status column.  Also, you did not include the expected output.

Comment: their is an intermediate state between login in and not ready ie; can we consider the time from 3 to 6 as available ?

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - The status column is ActivityCode, those #'s map back to the list I provided in my initial post.  Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @SteveM. so all other intervals except the ones specified above are not available ones

Comment: @SanalSunny - yes, the time from 3 to 6 is available. The time from 5 to 4 is also available

Comment: Expected output has been added to the original post

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY `Date` (looks like you need to derive this from the parts of the `TimeStamp` column), `AgentNum` and `AgentName`.

For the `TotalTimeLoggedIn`, SUM a CASE Expression, WHEN the Activity is a "Login", the DateDiff between that TimeStamp and the result of a SubSelect that gets the next (Top 1) "Logout" activity for the same `Agent`.

Do something similar with the "Ready" & "Not Ready" Activities to get `TotalTimeNotReady`, and you already know how to derive `TotalTimeAvailable` from those two.

Answer (score 0):

> So this is how far I got and i think its a partial solution. What you
>   still will need to do is some how update your 2nd temp table to 'push'
>   the values up so you get 1,2, or n number of rows depending on the no
>   of ActivityCode(s)

---

```
create table #Temp_Data
(
[TimeStamp] datetime null
,AgentNum int null
,AgentName varchar(10) null
,ActivityCode int null
)
insert into #Temp_Data values
('2018-11-19 07:53:06',      10      ,'Jane',           3)
,('2018-11-19 08:14:11',      10      ,'Jane',          6)
,('2018-11-19 08:19:12',      10      ,'Jane',          5)
,('2018-11-19 11:53:08',      10      ,'Jane',           4)
,('2018-11-19 13:01:16',      10      ,'Jane',           3)
,('2018-11-19 14:53:06',      10      ,'Jane',           6)
,('2018-11-19 14:59:16',      10      ,'Jane',           5)
,('2018-11-19 15:22:22',      10      ,'Jane',           6)
,('2018-11-19 15:31:25',     10      ,'Jane',           5)
,('2018-11-19 16:53:10',      10      ,'Jane',           4)

('2018-11-19 06:53:06',      11      ,'Bob',           3)
,('2018-11-19 07:14:11',      11      ,'Bob',          6)
,('2018-11-19 08:19:12',      11      ,'Bob',          5)
,('2018-11-19 10:53:08',      11      ,'Bob',           4)
,('2018-11-19 12:01:16',      11      ,'Bob',           3)
,('2018-11-19 13:53:06',      11      ,'Bob',           6)
,('2018-11-19 14:59:16',      11      ,'Bob',           5)
,('2018-11-19 15:29:22',      11      ,'Bob',           6)
,('2018-11-19 15:31:25',     11      ,'Bob',           5)
,('2018-11-19 16:53:10',      11      ,'Bob',           4)


--drop table #Temp_Data_1
create table #Temp_Data_1
( [TimeStamp] datetime null
,AgentName varchar(10) null
,[3_] varchar(20) null
,[6_] varchar(20) null
,[5_] varchar(20) null
,[4_] varchar(20) null
)

insert into #Temp_Data_1
select *
from (
select [TimeStamp]
,AgentNum
,AgentName
,ActivityCode
--, Rank_1 = rank() over ( partition by AgentName order by [TimeStamp]  ) 
from  #Temp_Data
) as s
--where ActivityCode in ('3','6','5','4')
PIVOT
(
    Count(AgentNum)
    For ActivityCode in ([3],[6],[5],[4])
)AS pvt

update  #Temp_Data_1
set [3_] = [TimeStamp]
where [3_] = 1


update  #Temp_Data_1
set [6_] = [TimeStamp]
where [6_] = 1


update  #Temp_Data_1
set [5_] = [TimeStamp]
where [5_] = 1


update  #Temp_Data_1
set [4_] = [TimeStamp]
where [4_] = 1

select  *  from  #Temp_Data_1
```